# Mapping 2D NSArray into 1D with NSIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use a 1D array like a 2D this way but I can't figure it out.
Given an array like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5];
```

Is it possible to acces '4' using an NSIndexPath defined like this?:

```
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
```

Comment: Huh, what? What is `NSIndexPath` doing here? How is it related to `NSArray`?

Comment: Ya actually now that I think about it how do you expect to index 1,1 to 4?

Comment: Karlos, that's a single-dimensional array of NSNumbers, not a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @ghettopia: I believe Karlos knows that; he just wants to map a 2D array to a 1D array.

Comment: @mipadi I changed the title to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, you can use an index path of dimension A to walk an array of dimension B.  You can also make a rule that says what to do when you have extra dimensions in either your path or in your array.

That rule can look something like this:  if I run out of path dimensions, return whatever object I find at the end of the path.  If I run out of array dimensions (like the case in your question) discard the remainder of the path and return whatever non-array I found.

In code:

```
- (id)objectInArray:(id)array atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {

    // the end of recursion
    if (![array isKindOfClass:[NSArray self]] || !path.length) return array;

    NSUInteger nextIndex = [path indexAtPosition:0];

    // this will (purposely) raise an exception if the nextIndex is out of bounds
    id nextArray = [array objectAtIndex:nextIndex];

    NSUInteger indexes[27]; // maximum number of dimensions per string theory :)
    [path getIndexes:indexes];
    NSIndexPath *nextPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes+1 length:path.length-1];

    return [self objectInArray:nextArray atIndexPath:nextPath];
}
```

Call it like this...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1, [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hi", @"there", nil], @3, nil];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:1];
indexPath = [indexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:1];

NSLog(@"%@", [self objectInArray:array atIndexPath:indexPath]);
```

This produces the output "there", for the given index path.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to do something like this:

```
NSArray* array= @[ @[ @1,@2,@3 ] , @[@2, @4, @6] ];
NSIndexPath* path=[[NSIndexPath alloc]initWithIndexes: (const NSUInteger[]){0,0} length:2];
NSLog(@"%@",array [[path indexAtPosition: 1]] [[path indexAtPosition: 0]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* myArray= @[ @[ @"Zero.Zero",@"Zero.One",@"Zero.Two" ] , @[ @"One.Zero", @"One.One", @"One.Two" ] ] ;
NSLog(@"%@",  myArray[1][2] ) ;   // logs 'One.Two'
```